# How to loop through the custom post type once you have added to an existing query

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am a bit stuck with a project and I would appreciate if someone could help me with that one.
I've searched for some references everywhere (firstly of course here) and I only could find bits and pieces of what I need.

I need to end up with the following structure:

```
<!--LOOP 1 -  WORD PRESS PARENT PAGES-->
<div id="post-parent1-name">...</div>

<div id="post-parent2-name">

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class='post-content'><?php the_content(); ?></div>

    <!--LOOP 2 -  WORD PRESS CHILDREN PAGES-->
    <div id="post-child1-name">...</div>

    <div id="post-child2-name">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  

        <!--LOOP 3 - WORD PRESS CUSTOM POST TYPE-->
        <div id="custom-post-type-name">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <div class='post-content'><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="post-child3-name">...</div>

</div>

<div id="post-parent3-name">...</div>
<div id="post-parent4-name">...</div>
```

I've used the following filter in my functions.php to add the custom post type to the query:

```
<?php
 function insert_post( $query ) {
 if ( $post->post_name == 'my_parent_post_name' && $query->is_main_query() )
 $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'my_custom_post_type') );
 return $query;
 }
 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'insert_post' );
?>
```

I've managed to get the first and the second one to work fine however I could not figure out how to get the third one to work **(which is my custom post type)** in order to bring me the title, content and thumbnail respectively.

Sorry guys, I know that looks a bit confusing however I hope that makes sense.

Cheers,
Doug.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours trying to find the answer for that problem I finally achieved my goal using:

`<?php global $wp_query; ?>`

[Function Reference/query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

I am still not quite sure about the usage of the action `add_action( 'pre_get_posts' , 'ucc_pre_get_posts_filter' );`, although I've manage to add a new array to my pre-existing query without affecting it:

**Pre-existing query:**

`<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page', 'order'=>'ASC', 'post_parent' => 0)); ?>`

*First Loop here*

**Inclusion of a new array using $wp_query:**

`<?php
                                                    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
                                                    query_posts( $args );
                                                ?>`

*Third Loop here*

Cheers guys!